# Create domain and get domain verification code using graph API from third party

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graphql

Hi i'm trying to create domain verifications from my ecommerce for facebook.
For that (what i found in the documentation) is that you need to create a domain using the graph API `https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/<business-id>/owned_domains` and sending the token, the problem is when i send the application token, the token which the user give us the permissions i'm getting the error `Tried accessing nonexisting field (owned_domains) on node type (Business)` but when i use the user token i get a correct response

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "someId",
      "domain_name": "hello.org"
    }
  ]
}
```

My question is:

Can you create and get the domain verification code for a domain in fb using not the user token but the thir party (ecommerce) integration token?